# how to evaluate variables in xslt messages when run on MarkLogic

Tags: xml, xslt, marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a xslt that is evaluated in Marklogic (via `xdmp:xslt-invoke`).  I am trying to evaluate a variable inside a `xsl:message` tag, however, when Marklogic encounters the message, it doesn't evaluate the variable, but simply displays the text inside it.

For example:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="//xpath"/>
    <xsl:message terminate="yes">Terminating <xsl:value-of select="$x"/></xsl:message>        
</xsl:template>
```

When this is evaluated, I see something like this in the output:

```
[XSLT] XSLT-MSGTERMINATE: (err:XTMM9000)<xsl:message terminate="yes"><xsl:text>"Terminating "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$x"/><xsl:text>"&#10; />"</xsl:text></xsl:message> -- xsl:message instruction called with terminate
```

Is there a way to actually evaluate and display the value of $x in the message?

Answer (score 1):

While `xsl:message terminate="yes"` wasn't evaluating the variables.  I was able to evaluate the variables through `xdmp:eval` in the following way and present the termination message as a `fn:error`

```
<xsl:template match="//some xpath condition">
    <xsl:variable name="x" select="//someXpath string value"/>
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
        <xsl:value-of
            select="
                xdmp:eval(concat(
                'xquery version ''1.0-ml'';',
                'let $message := concat(''Terminating with value ''', ',', '''', $x, ''')',
                'let $_error := error(xs:QName(''Error''), $message)',
                'return $_error'
                ))"
        /></xsl:message></xsl:template>
```

The following `xdmp:eval` will evaluate the `$x` variable value correctly.